# How to use PrincipalContext in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, principalcontext

I have created a web application in .NET Core 2.0 where I would like to use a `PrincipalContext` from namespace  `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

I want to validate user agains Active Directory like this:

```
private static ClaimsIdentity ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            var domain = GetDomainByLogin(userName);

            using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate))
            {
                if (!pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password)) return null;

                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception(UserNotFound);
                }

                var id = new ClaimsIdentity();

                id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, userName));
                id.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, userName));

                var groups = user.GetGroups();
                var roles = groups.Select(x => new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, x.Name));

                id.AddClaims(roles);

                return id;
            }
        }
```

How can I use the `PrincipalContext` (`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`) in `.NET Core 2.0`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible get the preview version of `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` for `.NET Core 2.0`.

From [myget](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement). It is possible get via Nuget package via this [feed](https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json). 
The extended discussion about that is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089).

**Update:**
Latest working preview is [here](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/4.5.0-preview1-25726-06).