# Migrate Principal from ASP.NET Web API 2 to ASP.NET Core (AuthenticationFilter)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm thinking about how can I migrate a ASP.NET Web API 2 project to ASP.NET Core.

Current project details:

1. All API controllers are inheriting a *BaseController*.
2. *BaseController* is decorated with a custom attribute (*CustomAuthenticationAttribute*)
3. *CustomAuthenticationAttribute* implements *IAuthenticationFilter* and inside *AuthenticateAsync* method:

   - Based on the HTTP headers I'm retrieving details about the user from the database
   - In case the user is not found, I'm populating *HttpAuthenticationContext.ErrorResult* and return (cutting the pipeline)
   - If I find the user, a statement similar to this is executed: *HttpAuthenticationContext.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { })* in order to set the principal.
4. The *BaseController* contains the following code:

   ```
   protected MyIdentityClass Identity
   {
     get
     {
       if (RequestContext.Principal == null)
       {
         return null;
       }
       return RequestContext.Principal.Identity as MyIdentityClass ;
     }
   }
   ```
5. I am **able** to access the Identity inside any API method.
6. Inside unit tests, I can assign the principal with the following code:

   `Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { });`

My question is this: How can I port this code to ASP.NET Core without modifying all my API controllers and test classes? I've already read [Migrate from ClaimsPrincipal.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-3.0) but it doesn't satisfy my needs.

Comment: you can move the authenticate part to the middleware and inject it in each controller as applicable.do the same for  service calls , db context , logs can create a service client .

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816418/how-to-use-principalcontext-in-net-core-2-0/45869723#45869723)?

Comment: @Aravind This is something I want to avoid because it will break all my tests (+5k tests / ~ 160 controllers)

Comment: @MuhammadHannan Thank you but it isn't what I'm searching for.